# Asking many people to 'jeter un coup d'œil'

Tags: choix-de-mot, pluriel

When I ask someone to take a glance at something, I use:

> jeter un coup d'œil

In the following phrase, do I still say "un coup d'œil" or do I use "des coups d'œil(s)"?

> C'est peut-être une bonne idée de demander à Rod, Jane et Freddy de jeter un coup d'œil.

Answer (score 13):

Since you assume that everyone will only take once glance, there is no reason to use the plural form, so the following is correct:

> Ils vont y jeter un coup d'œil.

That said, the plural form of "coup d'œil" is "[coups d'œil](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/coup_d%E2%80%99%C5%93il)" (just because you give more glances doesn't mean you use more eyes), <strike>but I don't see any valid context to use it</strike> as illustrated in Gilles' example in the comments.

Comment: « Malgré mes coups d'œil répétés, je n'ai rien vu. »

Comment: The expression is « jeter un coup d'œil. » There is no plural form.

Answer (score 8):

Like Joubarc said, there is no need for a plural. Even in this context:

> Il faudrait régulièrement jeter un coup d'œil ...

or

> Il va jeter un coup d'œil régulier à ...

Remark: the plural form of `œil` is `yeux`.

Comment: +1 for the plural form of oeil